# Java Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx

I am running Java Spring Boot and receiving this error. How can it be resolved? We see it during runtime. I tried searching github and google, didn't see any resolutions.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: hi @fantaghirocco no, I already saw that answer, I am not using Cassandra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using maven or gradle? Probably your project is missing a dependency. Probably this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-core

Comment: Please add the code lines as an example, in your solution, it works by the way,  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: We prefer not to use links in Stackoverflow, since sometimes links can be expired/archived, but we can do both, thanks